# Volume law spread after Hamiltonian evolution

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

Start with an $n \times n$ lattice, with each qubit initialized to the state $|0\rangle$. Then, apply the Hadamard gate on each qubit. Then, evolve the system under the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
    H = \sum_{l, m \in [n]} \text{Z}_l \text{Z}_m,
\end{equation}
for $d$ time steps.
Note that the final state of the Hamiltonian can be written as
\begin{equation}
    |\psi\rangle_{\text{final}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n^{2}}}} \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}^{n^{2}}} \sum_{l, m \in [n]} e^{-i d (-1)^{x_l + x_m}} |x\rangle,
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ bit of $x$.

I could not formally prove that this state abides by a volume law entanglement spread and that is where I needed help.

---

Since the Hamiltonian allows for long-range interactions, it is qualitatively evident that the entanglement will follow a volume-law spread.

Comment: It looks like an homework question. What did you try so far?

Comment: $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle$.

Comment: Edited to reflect where I am stuck at.

Comment: You seem to be basically at the result already. You just have to apply those operators to your input state. However, perhaps I can point out: the all-zeros state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian!

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I realized that the question had gotten quite trivial. I significantly changed the question to something more interesting.